How to add custom option in the right click menu (Windows 11)
I want to add an option in the Context Menu when right clicking on any file (Windows 11).

I already changed the menu appearance so it looks like Windows 10's menu, and I already added an option in the Registry that opens PowerShell and prints Hello World.

What do I change in the Registry so my TestHelloWorld option appears every time I click on any type of file, a little like Properties or Open would show up in any case?

I already tried HKCR\txtfilelegacy\shell\ to test it on .txt, but that didn't work


Current Context Menu:  
Where I'd like to add it:  

A Key would be created within HKCR\*\shell - I'll create an answer later, as I don't have time at the moment (example). There's also a way to add the option to the new condensed default context menu in Windows 11 (otherwise you either have to hold down Shift while right-clicking or change it back to the Windows 10 version). Position can be either: Top, Middle, or Bottom

@JW0914 I will try adding a key to the *\shell\

@rcp Easy way  using an app like Easy Context Menu https://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/
